# Hibernate return result is different direct query

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate createcriteria to join few tables and query data from database. I found the result return is different compare to the result query directly from SQL client with the SQL statement generated by hibernate. 
The result return by Hibernate is more than direct query.
I am just wondering why this will happen?

Below is the SQL statement generated by Hibernate createcriteria. I had replace the value with the "?" placeholder in the statement.

```
select this_.mrctBizId as mrctBizI1_5_13_, this_.name as 
 name11_5_13_, 
 from go.go_mrct_business this_ 
 inner join go.go_location location3_ on this_.LocId=location3_.locId 
 inner join go.go_state state4_ on location3_.StateId=state4_.stateId 
 inner join go.go_country country5_ on state4_.CountryId=country5_.countryId 
 left outer join go.go_mrct_off_date holiday7_ on this_.mrctBizId=holiday7_.MrctBizId and ( (holiday7_.startDt<='2015-05-23' and holiday7_.endDt>='2015-05-23') ) 
left outer join go.go_mrct_business gomrctbusi13_ on holiday7_.MrctBizId=gomrctbusi13_.mrctBizId 
left outer join go.go_mrct_off_day offday6_ on this_.mrctBizId=offday6_.MrctBizId and ( offday6_.offDay=7 ) 
left outer join go.go_mrct_business gomrctbusi15_ on offday6_.MrctBizId=gomrctbusi15_.mrctBizId 
inner join go.go_service service1_ on this_.mrctBizId=service1_.MrctBizId 
inner join go.go_category gocategory2_ on service1_.CatId=gocategory2_.catId 
left outer join go.go_mrct_business gomrctbusi20_ on service1_.MrctBizId=gomrctbusi20_.mrctBizId     
where offday6_.MrctBizId is null 
and holiday7_.MrctBizId is null 
and this_.enabled=true 
and service1_.enabled=true 
and gocategory2_.catId=11 
and country5_.countryId=1 
and state4_.stateId=2 
and location3_.locId=6 
and this_.bizStartTime<=CAST('10:10:00' AS time) 
and this_.bizEndTime>=CAST('10:10:00' AS time) ;
```

Comment: Please add more details like your "direct" sql query and the criteria query .

Comment: The SQL statement above is the query generated by hibernate createCriteria, and I am also using this SQL statement to direct query via SQL client, but both return different result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do comparisons like this, because Hibernate has a first level cache (session) and if you have modified objects in this cache, they will be swizzled to those objects in the result that have the same id. This is the concept behind repeatable read on an object guaranteed by Hibernate.

Direct SQL bypasses Hibernate's cache and so the results will not reflect any local changes in your Hibernate session.

If you really want to do this comparison, ensure you have a clean session and no other updates are occurring against the tables you are querying.

Comment: Even if I test it via JUnit test? I tried with JUnit, the result still the same.

Comment: Yes, the semantics don't change how it is invoked. You can make sure that your session is clear and this is the only query that is run within the session. But I still will not recommend doing such a comparison.